# How to initialize Firebase V9 database in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I think I'm getting confused between `firebase-admin` and `Web SDK` I simply would like to connect a scheduled job that will push data into my `Real-time database`

Project structure

[image]

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.14.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

How can I correctly connect my scheduled cloud function to Firebase Database?

Here is my index.js where most scheduled functions will live

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");
//const { push } = require("firebase/database")

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "myurl"
});

const database = admin.database();

exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub
  .schedule("every 1 minutes")
  .onRun((context) => {
    push(database, "/hello", {
        message: "world"
    })
    return console.log("This will be run every 1 minutes!");
  });
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the Admin SDK itself to add the data?

Comment: Are you able to provide an example? I have been using V9 functions such as push, update, set etc...@Dharmaraj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Admin SDK is not totally modular like the client SDK yet so you'll have to use the namespaced syntax if using the Admin SDK:

```
const db = admin.database();

exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub
  .schedule("every 1 minutes")
  .onRun((context) => {
    console.log("This will be run every 1 minutes!");
 
    return db.ref('hello').push({ name: "Hellow" });
  });
```

Comment: Thank you! I got all mixed up between that two